# error while using make command in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, command, charm-crypto

I'm trying to install Charm library in python 3.8, but when I use the `make` command this error occurs, does anyone know how to solve this problem?
This is the tutorial I'm using to install the library [http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ace/install-charm.html](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eace/install-charm.html)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Charm-Crypto-0.43$ make
Setup build/staging directories
set -x
set +x
Building the Charm Framework
/usr/bin/python distribute_setup.py
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.42.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 497, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 492, in main
    tarball = download_setuptools()
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
make: *** [Makefile:28: all] Error 1
```

After trying the following command `sed -i 's/http/https/' distribute_setup.py` I got this error

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Charm-Crypto-0.43$ sed -i 's/http/https/' distribute_setup.py
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Charm-Crypto-0.43$ make
Setup build/staging directories
set -x
set +x
Building the Charm Framework
/usr/bin/python distribute_setup.py
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.42.tar.gz
Extracting in /tmp/tmpILliHz
Now working in /tmp/tmpILliHz/distribute-0.6.42
Installing Distribute
Before install bootstrap.
Scanning installed packages
No setuptools distribution found
running install
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-16765.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.
/usr/bin/python setup.py build  
Extracting in /tmp/tmpNUFalo
Now working in /tmp/tmpNUFalo/distribute-0.6.42
Building a Distribute egg in /home/ubuntu/Charm-Crypto-0.43
/home/ubuntu/Charm-Crypto-0.43/distribute-0.6.42-py2.7.egg
('Platform:', 'Linux')
('Config file:', '/home/ubuntu/Charm-Crypto-0.43/config.mk')
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm
copying charm/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm
copying charm/config.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core
copying charm/core/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/crypto
copying charm/core/crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/crypto
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/engine
copying charm/core/engine/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/engine
copying charm/core/engine/protocol.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/engine
copying charm/core/engine/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/engine
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/math
copying charm/core/math/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/math
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test
copying charm/test/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/pk_vrf_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/abenc_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/grpsig_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/commit_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/chamhash_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/pksig_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/pkenc_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/rsa_alg_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/dabenc_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/ibenc_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/hibenc_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
copying charm/test/schemes/encap_bchk05_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/schemes
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/toolbox
copying charm/test/toolbox/conversion_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/toolbox
copying charm/test/toolbox/secretshare_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/toolbox
copying charm/test/toolbox/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/toolbox
copying charm/test/toolbox/paddingschemes_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/toolbox
copying charm/test/toolbox/symcrypto_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/test/toolbox
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/ecgroup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/pairinggroup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/IBSig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/xmlserialize.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/eccurve.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/ABEncMultiAuth.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/bitstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/sigmaprotocol.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/ABEnc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/schemebase.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/paddingschemes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/secretutil.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/DFA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/matrixops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/pairingcurves.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/symcrypto.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/specialprimes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/FSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/securerandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/Commit.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/policytree.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/IBEnc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/redundancyschemes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/paddingschemes_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/secretshare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/node.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/PKSig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/iterate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/PKEnc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/Hash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/integergroup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/zknode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/reCompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/enum.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/conversion.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
copying charm/toolbox/hash_module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/toolbox
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/zkp_compiler
copying charm/zkp_compiler/zkp_generator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/zkp_compiler
copying charm/zkp_compiler/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/zkp_compiler
copying charm/zkp_compiler/zk_demo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/zkp_compiler
copying charm/zkp_compiler/zkparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/zkp_compiler
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/encap_bchk05.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/protocol_schnorr91.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/chamhash_adm05.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/sigma1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/sigma3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/protocol_cns07.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/dabe_aw11.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/sigma2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/pk_vrf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/chamhash_rsa_hw09.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
copying charm/schemes/pre_mg07.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_waters09.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_ckrs09.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_cllww12_z.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_waters09_z.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_lsw08.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_bf01.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_waters05_z.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_sw05.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_bb03.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_CW13_z.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
copying charm/schemes/ibenc/ibenc_waters05.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/ibenc
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/abenc
copying charm/schemes/abenc/abenc_waters09.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/abenc
copying charm/schemes/abenc/abenc_lsw08.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/abenc
copying charm/schemes/abenc/dfa_fe12.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/abenc
copying charm/schemes/abenc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/abenc
copying charm/schemes/abenc/pk_hve08.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/abenc
copying charm/schemes/abenc/abenc_bsw07.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/abenc
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pkenc
copying charm/schemes/pkenc/pkenc_elgamal85.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pkenc
copying charm/schemes/pkenc/pkenc_paillier99.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pkenc
copying charm/schemes/pkenc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pkenc
copying charm/schemes/pkenc/pkenc_cs98.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pkenc
copying charm/schemes/pkenc/pkenc_rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pkenc
copying charm/schemes/pkenc/pkenc_rabin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pkenc
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/hibenc
copying charm/schemes/hibenc/hibenc_bb04.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/hibenc
copying charm/schemes/hibenc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/hibenc
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_cl03.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_hess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_ecdsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_CW13_z.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_cl04.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_schnorr91.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_rsa_hw09.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_hw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_waters05.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_waters09.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_cllww12_z.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_boyen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_cyh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_bls04.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_chch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_chp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
copying charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_waters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/pksig
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/commit
copying charm/schemes/commit/commit_pedersen92.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/commit
copying charm/schemes/commit/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/commit
copying charm/schemes/commit/commit_gs08.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/commit
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/grpsig
copying charm/schemes/grpsig/groupsig_bgls04.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/grpsig
copying charm/schemes/grpsig/groupsig_bgls04_var.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/grpsig
copying charm/schemes/grpsig/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/schemes/grpsig
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
copying charm/adapters/ibenc_adapt_hybrid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
copying charm/adapters/pkenc_adapt_chk04.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
copying charm/adapters/kpabenc_adapt_hybrid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
copying charm/adapters/pksig_adapt_naor01.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
copying charm/adapters/pkenc_adapt_hybrid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
copying charm/adapters/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
copying charm/adapters/pkenc_adapt_bchk05.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
copying charm/adapters/dabenc_adapt_hybrid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
copying charm/adapters/abenc_adapt_hybrid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
copying charm/adapters/ibenc_adapt_identityhash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/adapters
running build_ext
building 'charm.core.math.pairing' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/math
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/math/pairing
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/utilities
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/benchmark
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-U5f0ID/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DBENCHMARK_ENABLED=1 -Icharm/core/utilities/ -Icharm/core/benchmark/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.o
In file included from charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.c:1717:
charm/core/benchmark/benchmark_util.c: In function ‘InitBenchmark’:
charm/core/benchmark/benchmark_util.c:100:3: warning: ‘RAND_pseudo_bytes’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  100 |   RAND_pseudo_bytes(group->bench_id, ID_LEN);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/bio.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:14,
                 from charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.h:44,
                 from charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.c:30:
/usr/include/openssl/rand.h:44:1: note: declared here
   44 | DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(int RAND_pseudo_bytes(unsigned char *buf, int num))
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-U5f0ID/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DBENCHMARK_ENABLED=1 -Icharm/core/utilities/ -Icharm/core/benchmark/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c charm/core/utilities/base64.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/utilities/base64.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-U5f0ID/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DBENCHMARK_ENABLED=1 -Icharm/core/utilities/ -Icharm/core/benchmark/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c charm/core/benchmark/benchmarkmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/benchmark/benchmarkmodule.o
charm/core/benchmark/benchmarkmodule.c: In function ‘Benchmark_print’:
charm/core/benchmark/benchmarkmodule.c:234:77: warning: format ‘%S’ expects argument of type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 2 has type ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} [-Wformat=]
  234 | ults = _PyUnicode_FromFormat("<--- Results --->\nCPU Time:  %Sms\nReal Time: %Ss\nAdd:\t%i\nSub:\t%i\nMul:\t%i\nDiv:\t%i\nExp:\t%i\nPair:\t%i\n",
      |                                                             ~^
      |                                                              |
      |                                                              int *

  235 | al, self->op_add, self->op_sub, self->op_mult, self->op_div, self->op_exp, self->op_pair);
      |                                                               

charm/core/benchmark/benchmarkmodule.c:234:94: warning: format ‘%S’ expects argument of type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 3 has type ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} [-Wformat=]
  234 | _FromFormat("<--- Results --->\nCPU Time:  %Sms\nReal Time: %Ss\nAdd:\t%i\nSub:\t%i\nMul:\t%i\nDiv:\t%i\nExp:\t%i\nPair:\t%i\n",
      |                                                             ~^
      |                                                              |
      |                                                              int *

  235 |  self->op_sub, self->op_mult, self->op_div, self->op_exp, self->op_pair);
      |                                                               

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-U5f0ID/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-U5f0ID/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/utilities/base64.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/benchmark/benchmarkmodule.o -lpbc -lgmp -lcrypto -o /home/ubuntu/Charm-Crypto-0.43/charm/core/math/pairing.so
building 'charm.core.math.integer' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/math/integer
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-U5f0ID/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DBENCHMARK_ENABLED=1 -Icharm/core/utilities/ -Icharm/core/benchmark/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c charm/core/math/integer/integermodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/charm/core/math/integer/integermodule.o
charm/core/math/integer/integermodule.c: In function ‘bnToLongObj’:
charm/core/math/integer/integermodule.c:129:19: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘BIGNUM’ {aka ‘struct bignum_st’}
  129 |   for(i = 0; i < m->dmax; i++) {
      |                   ^~
charm/core/math/integer/integermodule.c: In function ‘mpzToBN’:
charm/core/math/integer/integermodule.c:166:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘bn_expand2’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  166 |   if(bn_expand2(b, size) == NULL)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
charm/core/math/integer/integermodule.c:166:26: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
  166 |   if(bn_expand2(b, size) == NULL)
      |                          ^~
charm/core/math/integer/integermodule.c:170:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘bn_correct_top’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  170 |   bn_correct_top(b);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [Makefile:29: all] Error 1
```

Comment: It looks like it's using Python 2.7, not 3.8. Since it tries to call /usr/bin/python, try to install package `python-is-python3`.

Comment: The installer uses http while https is required. Try downloading it (`wget ...`), then edit it, change the http into https and `pip install`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet can u plz explain more I'm still a beginner at this. what should I write after the wget command?

Comment: As the message says, you don't have the permission to write in `/usr/local`. Either install as superuser (`sudo make`) or, if you are not superuser, ask an administrator. You could also try to install in another directory where you have write permissions but if you are really new to all this I do not recommend it. Once you will have fixed this you will have to work around another, C compilation, error. It will be time to contact the developers of this application.

Answer (score 0):

The installer uses `http` while `https` is required. Try downloading it (`wget ...`), then edit it, change the `http` into `https` (not tested):

```
wget https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/releases/download/v0.43/Charm-Crypto-0.43_Python2.7.tar.gz
tar xf Charm-Crypto-0.43_Python2.7.tar.gz
cd Charm-Crypto-0.43
./configure.sh
sed -i 's/http/https/' distribute_setup.py
make
```

And if this fix works, please let the developers know such that they can update their installer.

Comment: I edited my question, I did what you said but another error occurred, I've added it now plz check it and tell me what do u think?